# reading the Nth column of a .txt

Tags: fortran, multiple-columns

I work in fortran

I know that you can read several columns by doing :

> read (20,*) a,b,c

but I have a document with something like 25 columns
but i would like to read the 19th without having to use trash variables like i do know.

I use :

> read (20,*) trash1,trash2,[...],trash18,VariaWanted

I would like to know if there is a "cleaner" way to do so. Especially if I can use an integer to say where it is, so I can put it in "in variable" of function or subroutine.

Comment: read into a line and process it or read into an array

Comment: what types are `a,b,c` ?

Comment: a,b,c have the right type to read what I want (here real(8))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
real, dimension (25) :: temp
real :: keep
read (20,*) temp
keep = temp (19)
```

Comment: Also thank, it is the same principle than my trashes variables, but cleaner ^^. It work. It is less pretty than the solution gave by Vladimir, but I can treat files that are not formated !

Answer (score 4):

You do not show the actual format of your file. Often the tables use fixed column width. Then you can just use explicit format to read just that character columns in the row.

```
read (20,'(t42,f8.0)') a
```

Provided you want to read a real that uses 8 characters and starts on character column 42.

Comment: Yes ! Thank you, that a really clean way to do it. And most of the files I have to use are like that.